# How do I disable auto-negotiation on DD-WRT?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, bridge

I have a WRT54GL router with DD-WRT firmware installed, and have the exact same situation as exposed in [this](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r23614389-DDWRT-Zyxel-P660HWt1-v2-WRT54GL-DDWRT) thread. The problem is, I don't know how to disable the auto-negotiation on the router administrator panel, as it says on the thread (I can't find the option).

How can I do it?

**Extra**: Just in case anyone else has had the same situation, is there anything else I should take into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup -> VLANs

http://www.informatione.gmxhome.de/DDWRT/Standard/V24BetaVPN/Vlan.html

Comment: This solution is outdated. There's no such VLAN settings in the newer dd-wrt versions.